# Sympfony MIgration checker is out of controll in my job

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony 6.2.1.0, am new to symfony.I have successfully created doctrine and ORM packages and .env file was created automatically. I also created an entity, but when i tried to create migration am getting the following error.

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "Malformed parameter "url"."

In DriverManager.php line 268:
                              
  Malformed parameter "url".  
                              

In MalformedDsnException.php line 12:
                                     
  Malformed database connection URL
```

I tried to create migration using the following command

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

My codes in .env file is as follows

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:Lisieux#10@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?serverVersion=5.7"
```

My database username is root and DB Name is symfony.

What is the error here?

Comment: You are missing the password in the DSN : `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:{PASSWORD}@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?serverVersion=10.11.2-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4"`

Comment: Nope, take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Comment: your password has # change it to '%23'. PS:don't post passwords

Comment: `#` has a special meaning in URLs, it's used to signal the [fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web).

Comment: @francisco Thanks for your comment. Please post it as answer.I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database), if the **username**, **password**, **host** or **database name** contain any character considered special in a URI (such as +, @, $, #, /, :, *, !, %), you must encode them.
So:

| character | urlencode |
| --- | --- |
| + | %2B |
| @ | %40 |
| $ | %24 |
| # | %23 |
| / | %2F |
| : | %3A |
| * | %2A |
| ! | %21 |
| % | %25 |